# Exclude a list of pairs of conditions from a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Imagine the following model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    doors = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I want to query it but I have a list of conditions that I want to exclude:

```
[(red, 4), (red, 5), (red, 6)]
```

The result being —for example— it'll show me red cars with 2 doors and any blue cars. I know I can iterate the exclusions list and pack lazy `.exclude(color=..., doors=...)` on top of each other, I just wondered if there was a nicer way like the `__in` modifier but one that can take two separate fields in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Car.objects.all()
exclude_conditions = [(red, 4), (red, 5), (red, 6)]
for colour, doors in exclude_conditions:
    queryset = queryset.exclude(colour=colour, doors=doors)
```

Or, you could build a list of [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects for each condition in the list, and `or` them together:

```
from operator import or_

queryset = Car.objects.all()
exclude_conditions = [(red, 4), (red, 5), (red, 6)]
exclude_qs = [Q(colour=colour, doors=doors) for (colour, doors) in exclude_conditions]
queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(or_, exclude_qs))
```

Which one you choose is really a matter of personal preference.

For the example you've given, you can simplify the query to

```
queryset = Car.objects.exclude(Q(colour="red", doors__in=[4, 5, 6])
```

However, it might not be worth the extra work to do this in practice.